# Can anyone help me identify what type of horns these are?

Tags: species-identification

I picked these up at an estate sale a few years ago and now need to identify them for shipping purposes.

They are 29x18x10.5 inches in size.

A friend who works in antiques believes the are over 100 years old based on the wood they are attached to and thinks they belong to some kind of ram. That's all the information I have on them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

[image: image 1]

[image: image with lengths]

Comment: almost certainly that of a goat (see [here](https://twitter.com/konatsu0224/status/922402606776950784), [here](https://www.fotolibra.com/gallery/182690/golden-guernsey-billy-goat/), and especially [here](https://pxhere.com/en/photo/1184510))

Answer (score 1):

Those look very much like "Catalina" goat horns. They're a popular trophy game to hunt, specifically for these sorts of displays. The goats themselves originate in Spain but are commonly found in the United States, now.